# "Get form from" connection isn´t available to link a list webpart to an infopath form

Tags: infopath, list-view, form, connection

Since a security update some web parts don´t display as they used to. I know it is due to the parameter of XLS timeout which I can´t change. 
Nevermind, I tried to find another solution to display my list in a nice tabular form.
I decided to create a customised view with infopath, then to add an infopath form on my website page and to link this web part to my list (displayed in a classical list webpart).
Sadly, I cannot link anything. The "get form from" option is grayed out, "not compatible with any other web parts on this page". I don´t understand it because my list webpart is displayed allright (with a connection to another filter etc.)

I don´t know what to do anymore, please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

After finding no answer on internet and after making many tests, I found the answer!
It is simply not possible to pass value to a form if the source webpart has filtered values. 
I decided to pass only one field (primary key of my list) and then to add rules inside my formular to auto-populate the cells. This was no easy thing (at least for me) but I finally achieved my goal.
Hope this will be useful for other lost souls like me.